# Printing in Python without a space

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printing

I've found this problem in a few different places but mine is slightly different so I can't really use and apply the answers.
I'm doing an exercise on the Fibonacci series and because it's for school I don't want to copy my code, but here's something quite similar.

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(one, two, three)
```

When this is printed it displays "1 2 3"
I don't want this, I'd like it to display it as "1,2,3" or "1, 2, 3"
I can do this by using an alteration like this

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(one, end=", ")
print(two, end=", ")
print(three, end=", ")
```

My real question is, is there a way to condense those three lines of code into one line because if I put them all together I get an error.

Thank you.

Comment: `help(print)` could have told you...

Answer (score 5):

Use [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print) function with `sep=', '` like this::

```
>>> print(one, two, three, sep=', ')
1, 2, 3
```

To do the same thing with an iterable we can use splat operator `*` to unpack it:

```
>>> print(*range(1, 5), sep=", ")
1, 2, 3, 4
>>> print(*'abcde', sep=", ")
a, b, c, d, e
```

help on `print`:

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python string `format`:

```
print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(one, two, three))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with or without a comma:

1) No spaces

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(one, two, three, sep="")
```

2) Comma with space

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(one, two, three, sep=", ")
```

3) Comma without space

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(one, two, three, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
print(', '.join(str(t) for t in (one,two,three)))
# 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
print("%d,%d,%d"%(one, two, three))
```